# SQL Server stored procedure not recognizing string.empty with like

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am passing `string.empty` from C# to a stored procedure in SQL Server.

I am using this `string.empty` with a `like` condition.

`seg_cd` is passed in as `string.empty` from C#.

```
LIKE '%' + @SEG_CD + '%'
```

But it fetches 0 records.

But when I do it like this in the stored procedure:

```
LIKE '%' + '' + '%'
```

It fetches the correct number of rows.

I tried trimming value in C# then also it is not working.

In C# `SEG_CD` is a string and in stored procedure, `SEG_CD` is `char(3)`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show your all code? Are you passing this `@SEG_CD` as a parameter?

Comment: @SEG_CD passed as string.empty...

Comment: Can you run sql trace or extended event to see what sql statement is passed to sql query engine ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the SQL datatype - `char(3)` will mean the string is **always** three characters long - padded to its defined length with spaces.

So you really check for

```
LIKE '%   %'
```

and that isn't found, it appears.

You should use `VARCHAR(3)` in SQL - then your string will be only as long as it really is! In the case you pass in `string.Empty`, it will be 0 characters long

Comment: ok.Suppose the string which is coming is from another SP and is of datatype varchar(255) but comes as blank so if trim it in SP...it should solve the problem..

Comment: @user662285: as long as it's defined as `char(3)` inside this stored procedure, you'll **always** have those problems!

Answer (score 1):

If@SEG_CD is a char(3) then it will be padded to 3 chars so it is equievelent to

`LIKE '%' + '   ' + '%'`

Use a varchar or nvarchar instead.